# How to mark a string in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, data-cleaning

Hy all,
I have encountered a problem while cleaning some data where I can't seem to "mark" this string as a string.
The problem is as follows:

```
select JobPosition,
case
when (JobPosition = 'Seniority level': 'Entry level'},) then 'Entry level'
else JobPosition
end
from JobsUSA
```

So the 'Seniority level': 'Entry level'},  I can't put inside '' that to mark it as a string.

I've tried different versions of putting '' in all kinds of places but without luck. I'm relatively new in SQL so all help would be appreciated.

I've tried to Google the problem but I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: Why is this tagged mysql when the title says microsoft sql? What's that lonely curly brace supposed to do? Please add an example.

Comment: What do you mean "mark this as a string" - what exactly are you asking? Perhaps you need to escape single quotes? What exactly have you Googled? Why have you a single brace? Why do you have a trailing comma?

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo for My/MicrosoftSQL... The single brace is there because I used a CHARINDEX to break up the long string into smaller pieces. Unfortunately, the only char that separates the string in the way I want is the }. These braces however are not the problem. The problem is in the ' sign that is part of that string. I hope I clarified it a little bit.

Comment: When using single quotes in a quoted string you need to double them up - `'this string contains ''single'' quotes'`

Comment: @Stu Thank you for the answer and your time, all the best :D.

Answer (score 0):

you can use function cast(), for example: cast(expr AS type)

Answer (score 0):

When using single quotes in a quoted string you need to double them up - 'this string contains ''single'' quotes'